# PHPFox Form Labels

Tags: label, phpfox

I have been studying phpfox, particularly the registration form. I am trying to remove the labels and add a placeholder within the input field. However, I have not been able to remove the labels. Editing the files within template/default/block/register/* seem to have no effect either.

Would someone be kind enough to offer guidance. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be cache problem. You must clear cache from admin then you will see the effect.

admincp → tools → Maintenance → Cache Manager